# Add OU of users / computers to a security group

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do 2 things.

1. Add all users in an OU to a security group
2. Add all computers in an OU to a security group

I can successfully get a list of the users or computers I need using:

```
get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase "ou=Users,ou=xx,ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=local" | FT SamAccountName
```

and

```
Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(name=compu*)" -searchbase "ou=xx,ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=local" | FT Name
```

These produce the exact details I need, both usernames and hostnames respectively.

I can add a group to my username using:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "%GROUPNAME%" -Members MyUsername
```

I can't get a group to add to a computer as it errors:

> Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'COMPUTERNAME' under: 'DC=XX,DC=LOCAL'. At line:1 char:1

I even tried being clever by using:

```
$Comps=Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(name=compu*)" -searchbase "ou=XX,ou=XX,dc=XX,dc=local" | FT Name

Add-ADGroupMember -identity $Comps -MemberOf '%GROUPNAME%'
```

but that just fails.

Tried similar with users:

```
$Userlist=get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase "ou=XX,ou=XX,ou=XX,ou=XX,dc=XX,dc=local" | FT SamAccountName

$Results = $Userlist | ForEach-Object {
 Add-ADGroupMember -identity %GROUPNAME% -members $_
}
```

Error:

> Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot bind parameter 'Members'. Cannot convert the
>   "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" value of type
>   "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" to type
>   "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPrincipal".
>   At line:4 char:105
>
> - ... %GROUPNAME% -members $_
> - ~~
> - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>     CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

As I've copied and pasted many examples and tried to sanitise, the OU statement locations are correct.

Currently I don't know if I should use `add-adgroupmember` or `add-adprinciplegroupmembership`, and I see I am making a fundamental error somewhere.

I appreciate I could output hostnames or usernames to a txt and import from that but it seems an unnecessary step.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`Add-ADPrincipalGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=win10-ps) as it accepts an object to add to a group

```
Get-ADUser -Filter -SearchBase "ou=Users,ou=xx,ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=local" | 
    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf Group_Name
```

Or to add computers:

```
Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(name=compu*)" -searchbase "ou=xx,ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=local" | 
    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf Group_Name
```

Also, don't format your results before you have dealt with them. At best it creates more work, at worst it breaks things. Let us know how you get on :) **NOTE:** I haven't tested this

Comment: aha, the first one needed a star after filter I assume?

Final questions if I may (and it looks crazily simple - thankyou!)…. how would I output the list to a file to confirm what actions it performed (e.g. audit trail saying "accounts 1, 2, 3, 4, added to Group_name).
also, how could I add more than one group at a time? "Group_name, Group_name2, Group_name3" ?

Comment: I'm wondering if I could output to screen and to file, maybe using "Write-Host "$user is in $group"" or similar, and use out-file or export-file for a txt or CSV?

Comment: @RobPowell Unfortunately, you're asking two other completely separate questions that I think would be more appropriate in their own separate post. But quick answer: 1) you could just use `Start-Transcript` or `Write-Host` inside each `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`  2) I don't think you can. I think it's just one group at a time. You could use `Add-ADGroup` I believe to use multiple groups at once :)

Comment: You are a legend. Thankyou squire! New question coming for formatting question.... :) :)

Comment: @RobPowell Remember to "mark as answer" and upvote and responses on this question that you found useful <3

Comment: Have done so, although upvote doesn't show as I'm only 13 rep and I need 15. Will come back for you though!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using `FT` unnecessarily. Normally you should return ADConputer, ADUser or any other ADObject but by using `Format-Table` you convert the object to an instance of a `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format`, which is basically a table and not usable in your case.

Comment: I was using FT so it only outputted the username, and hence why I tried it. That does explain why I couldn't do it as I did, thankyou so much for your comment!